# Using ServiceStack.Redis, how can I run strongly-typed read-only queries in a transaction

Tags: c#, transactions, redis, servicestack

I'm aware that I can increase performance of Redis queries by executing them in a transaction (and even more so in a dedicated pipeline).

The problem is that using the ServiceStack Redis client, I can execute the reads in a transaction but I cannot access the results. This is the code I have below:

```
User user = null;
Group group = null;

using (IRedisClient cacheClient = new RedisClient())
using (var trans = cacheClient.CreateTransaction())
{
    trans.QueueCommand(x =>
    {
        var userClient = x.As<User>();
        var userHash = userClient.GetHash<string>("Users");
        user = userClient.GetValueFromHash(userHash, userKey);
    });

    trans.QueueCommand(y =>
    {
        // Retrieve modules from cache
        var groupClient = y.As<Group>();
        var groupHash = groupClient.GetHash<string>("Groups");
        group = groupClient.GetValueFromHash(groupHash, groupKey);
    });

    trans.Commit()
}
```

The problem here is that the `user` and `group` variables are not set with the output from the transaction.

So, how can I run a series of different strongly-typed *read* queries in a transaction (or pipeline) and retrieve the results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do any **dependent reads** (operations relying on other read values) within a Redis transaction since the way that [transactions work in Redis](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) is that they all commands get batched and sent down to redis and executed as a single unit, so there's no opportunity to use a **read value** from within the same transaction.

The way you can ensure integrity is to use the [Redis WATCH](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) command to watch any keys before a transaction and if any of keys changed before the transaction it will throw when the transaction is committed. e.g:

```
var cacheClient = new RedisClient();

cacheClient.Watch("Users", "Groups");

var userHash = cacheClient.As<User>().GetHash<string>("Users");
var groupHash = cacheClient.As<Group>.GetHash<string>("Groups");

using (var trans = cacheClient.CreateTransaction())
{
    trans.QueueCommand(x =>
    {
        user = x.As<User>().GetValueFromHash(userHash, userKey);
    });

    trans.QueueCommand(y =>
    {
        group = y.As<Group>().GetValueFromHash(groupHash, groupKey);
    });

    trans.Commit();
}
```

Another alternative to transactions is to use [Redis server-side LUA](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-iredisclient-lua-apis).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So the upshot is I just can't do it? To clarify, I'm not so concerned about the data integrity, or making dependent reads, just about minimising the number of calls. It seems odd that I can queue up writes but there is no way to queue up *and use* reads.

Comment: @Digbyswift that's what WATCH lets you do, use read values from within a transaction. You can queue up reads, but as explained, there's no way to *use* those reads from another operation within the same transaction (this is by design, all operations in the same transaction are executed as a single unit). Using WATCH is the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I've used your implementation with WATCH but I just can't get that to work. `user` and `group` are always `null` once the commit takes place so I can't access the data.